# addFilter Rename ZendFramework

Tags: zend-framework, rename, zend-form-element

i need to Rename a file with Zend_File_Transfer() only if new file match with old one in the server using some convention like newfile-1.ext where the -1 is the string that is added but Rename filter is strange, i really dont understand so good.

For example, is necesary some like this:

```
if(file_exists($file)){
 $upload->addFilter('Rename', $file);
}
```

or Rename does it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from one of my apps. File is recvieved by an Zend_Form

```
        $upload->receive();
        $name = $upload->getFileName();

        $newFile = 'mynewfile.xyz'

        $filterFileRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
            'target'    => $this->path . $newFile, // path to file
            'overwrite' => true
        ));
        $file = $filterFileRename->filter($name);
```