# Zend AddFilter renaming specified file only not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got two files in my form that I want to give seperate new names. To do this I need to specify which file I want to change.

The zend documentation says this

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename', 'C:\picture\uploads', 'file2');
```

The documentation fails to say what 'file2' is... the name of the actual file, the name of the input field....

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

This is the form:

```
<input type="file" name="one">
<input type="file" name="two">
```

this goes in the controller

```
       $renamefile1 = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
         'target'    => $path.'/file1.csv', // path to file
         'overwrite' => true
        ));

       //rename file 2 to file2
       $renamefile2 = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
         'target'    => $path.'/file2.csv', // path to file
         'overwrite' => true
        ));


       $names = $upload->getfileName();
       $file1 = $renamefile1->filter($names["one"]);
       $file2 = $renamefile2->filter($names["two"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set a new destination path and limits it only to 'file2'
$upload->addFilter('Rename', 'C:\picture\uploads', 'file2');
```

> In that case the third parameter is for validate that if the file name
>   is file2 then it will override else it will add a new file in the
>   folder. The third parameter is a filter type for the name of the file.

You can also do that:

```
$upload->addFilter('Rename',
           array('target' => 'C:\picture\uploads',
                 'overwrite' => true));
```

For more example see it [addFilter Rename ZendFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712196/addfilter-rename-zendframework) You can also that which is this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just search for the method signature and check there?

```
/**
 * Adds a new filter for this class
 *
 * @param  string|Filter\FilterInterface $filter Type of filter to add
 * @param  string|array         $options   Options to set for the filter
 * @param  string|array         $files     Files to limit this filter to
 * @return AbstractAdapter
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException for invalid type
 */
public function addFilter($filter, $options = null, $files = null)
```

This is found in `Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\AbstractAdapter`